# JS jQuery | как избавиться от повторного клика используя функцию

Tags: jquery

Имеется следующий код:

```js
 function show(id){
  $(id).siblings().slideUp('slow');
  $(id).slideDown('slow');

  $(".Nav-Header p").click(function(){
   if($(this).css('border-bottom') == '0px none rgb(191, 0, 81)'){
    $(this).toggleClass("activeP");
    $(this).siblings("p").removeClass("activeP");
   }
  });
 };
```

```css
.Nav-Header{
 border-bottom: 2px solid #bf0051;
 padding: 0px 5px;
  height: 77px;
}
.Nav-Header p{
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 30px;
 padding: 0px 5px;
 padding-bottom: 10px;
 transition: 0s color, 0s border-bottom;
}
.Nav-Header p:hover{
 color: #bf0051;
}

.activeP{
 color: #bf0051!important;
 border-bottom: 3px solid  #bf0051!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="Nav-Header">
   <p onclick="show();" class="activeP">Блок1</p><p onclick="show();" id="Register">Блок2</p><p onclick="show();" >Блок3</p>
  </div><div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Когда нажимаешь на текст, то он принимает аргументы только после второго раза, я знаю что проблема в .click , но как можно обойтись без неё?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужен клик внутри клика. Проверка по свойствам CSS - это такая себе идея.

```js
$(".Nav-Header p").click(function() {
  // получаем слайд для переключения
  var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
  var content = $('#content-' + id);
  content.siblings().slideUp('slow');
  content.slideDown('slow');
  // переключаем только для неактивного таба
  if (!$(this).hasClass('activeP')) {
    $(this).addClass("activeP");
    $(this).siblings("p").removeClass("activeP");
  }
});
```

```css
.Nav-Header {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #bf0051;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  height: 77px;
}

.Nav-Header p {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 30px;
  padding: 0px 5px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  transition: 0s color, 0s border-bottom;
}

.Nav-Header p:hover {
  color: #bf0051;
}

.activeP {
  color: #bf0051!important;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #bf0051!important;
}

#content-2,
#content-3 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Nav-Header">
  <p class="activeP" data-id="1">Блок1</p>
  <p id="Register" data-id="2">Блок2</p>
  <p data-id="3">Блок3</p>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div>
  <div id="content-1">Содержимое Блока 1</div>
  <div id="content-2">Содержимое Блока 2</div>
  <div id="content-3">Содержимое Блока 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, про клик внутри клика я знаю, но я не нашёл как это исправить. Спасибо ещё раз!!!

Comment: можно в одну строку `$('#content-' + id).slideDown('slow').siblings().slideUp('slow');`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский , думал над этим, но оставил для читаемости раздельно. Разве что закешировать обращение к элементу можно, чтобы работало на пару миллисекунд быстрее.